# Reading a 200 mb json file takes 1.5 gb memory

Tags: c++, json

I'm using the json_spirit library in C++ to parse a 200 mb json file. What surprises me is that when read into memory in my program, 1.5 gb of my RAM gets used. Is this something that is expected when deserializing json?

Here is how I'm loading in the json file:

```
 std::ifstream istream(path.c_str());
 json_spirit::mValue val;
 json_spirit::read(istream, val);
```

Comment: I would advise you to raise the issue to the `json_spirit` maintainers, they might be aware (and provide advices/work around) or they might welcome the feedback and investigate the root cause. In any case, you certainly have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [rapidjson](http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/).

It is optimized for both memory usage and performance.

By using insitu-parsing option (i.e. it changes the source string of parsing), it only incurs 16 bytes per JSON value to store the DOM in 32-bit architecture. The string values will use pointers pointed to the modified source string.

I expect the memory usage will be much less.

On the other hand, rapidjson also support SAX-style parsing. If the application just need to traverse the JSON file from begin to end (e.g. doing some statistics), then SAX-style API will be even faster and very few memory consumption (program stack + maximum length of string value).

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is not JSON dependent. It's more a question of data structure overhead. If you have many small objects the administrative part becomes more and more relevant.

Although, more than seven times overhead, seems really excessive.